# JavaScript angle brackets in Flux Dispatcher source code

Tags: javascript

I was reading the [githab](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/src/Dispatcher.js#L109) source code for the Flux Dispatcher and find out the angle brackets syntax:

```
class Dispatcher<TPayload> { .... }
```

Is it new feature of the language or this is a sort of subset like typescript? The confusion part here is that file has `.js` extention.

And generally what this would mean in context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is for the Flow type checker from Facebook.

http://flowtype.org/